# Solr Indexing media fields

Tags: media, search

I have a bespoke media type that I'd like to index with solr. If I add a new field to an existing Media Type, I can add that field to the solr search using the interface found at admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_solr_index/fields

Fields from my Media Type do not show up on this list. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Are you indexing media itself?